# C++ Concatenation of Huge CStrings

Tags: c++, concatenation, c-strings

I got a problem with concatenation of huge CStrings in a legacy code base. The CStrings can contain base64 encoded files and so can be huge. At several points those CStrings are concatenated like this:

`result += CString(_T("Some smaller String")) + Huge_CString + _T("Some smaller String");`

This leads to several allocations and so we get huge memory peaks. Although this is done in parallel on multiple threads for different files. If they all come together I will finally get "Memory Exceptions".

What is the best way to handle this. If I could reduce the number of allocations that would help already. Right now I'm not looking for the perfect solution, but for a way to just reduce the peaks.

Comment: `A += B + C + D;` lots of temp strings.  `A+=B; A+=C; A+=D;`  less (no) temp strings.

Comment: The `operator+` will coerce the C strings to `std::string` and therefore leads to allocations as you said. Maybe you could consider using some C string API since these are C strings, like `strcat` or `strncat` from `<cstring>` ?

Comment: @Vivick almost `operator+` is overloaded for `CString` and c-strings; the rest is fine.

Comment: @Vivick Or don't. Benchmark string concatenation, including dynamic memory management on your behalf, of `std::string` or `CString` vs. rolling your own and using the likes of `strcat` and/or `strncat`. [There's a reason](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/), those functions are avoided : length determination.

Comment: @Richard Critten: Did a quick test on that, makes no difference

Comment: The c-strings tag is probably inappropriate as the question is (presumably) about MFC/ATL CString, not c-strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest essentially the same thing as Remy Lebeau, but using some different functions.  I'm not sure what version of MFC/ATL introduced the CString::Preallocate function, so it is possibly you are stuck with a version of MFC/ATL that does not have this function.

```
    CString result(_T("Initial string "));
    CString prefix(_T("Prefix string:"));
    CString suffix(_T(":Suffix string"));
    CString bigString(_T("This really isn't very big."));

    auto totalLength = result.GetLength() + prefix.GetLength() + bigString.GetLength() + suffix.GetLength();

    result.Preallocate(totalLength);

    result += prefix.GetString();
    result += bigString.GetString();
    result += suffix.GetString();
```

The calls to CString::GetString may or may not be useful.  You will likely get the same allocation behavior by just appending each of the sub-strings to `result`.

Comment: I completely missed `Preallocate()` while going through the `CString` methods. This is definitely much nicer. And  `operator+=` works without having to call `GetString()`: `result += prefix; result += bigString; result += suffix;` This avoids having to re-count the characters, or make temp objects.

Answer (score 4):

For editing large strings you may like to use non-contiguous types `rope` or [`unencoded_rope`](https://tzlaine.github.io/text/doc/html/boost/text/unencoded_rope.html) - *string types that are thread-safe, copy-on-write, or cheap to insert into the middle of*.

Comment: Will check that. Although I think I have to stick with CString in that legacy code base... or is there an easy way to convert?

Comment: @DanielG You can construct a rope from two iterators, which you can obtain from your `CString`.

Answer (score 2):

Pre-allocate a single `CString` of the desired concatenated length, and then copy the data from the smaller strings into its internal buffer, eg:

```
CString Huge_CString = ...;
LPCTSTR ss1 = TEXT("Some smaller String");
LPCTSTR ss2 = TEXT("Some smaller String");

int ss1_len = lstrlen(ss1);
int huge_len = Huge_CString.GetLength();
int ss2_len = lstrlen(ss2);

int concat_len = ss1_len + huge_len + ss2_len;

CString Concat_CString;
PXSTR buffer = Concat_CString.GetBufferSetLength(concat_len);
CString::CopyChars(buffer, ss1, ss1_len);
buffer += ss1_len;
CString::CopyChars(buffer, Huge_CSString.GetBuffer(), huge_len);
buffer += huge_len;
CString::CopyChars(buffer, ss2, ss2_len);
Concat_CString.ReleaseBuffer(total_len);

// use Concat_CString as needed...
```

Comment: thanks. that's what I was looking for. But I accept the other similar answer, since I'm going with that one.